Multithreading preemption of long-running method
I've run into the following situation a few times (both in C++ and Python), and I'm wondering a good (and correct) way to address it:
I'm working with two different libraries (so I can't change that code), which each provide classes similar to these:
// Call to do the "work"
class LongRunner
{
public:
  void runForAwhile();
  // Only interrupts runForAwhile() if it is currently running.
  // Doesn't do anything otherwise (ie, can still be called)
  void stopRunner();
};

// Override to define execution
class ExecutionBase
{
public:
  virtual void executeInSeparateThread();
  // Joins the execution thread. Can be overridden for additional cleanup.
  virtual void halt();
};

A non-threadsafe version of my derived class is:
class MyExecution : ExecutionBase
{
public:
  void executeInSeparateThread() override
  {
    doBeforeThings();
    long_runner_.runForAwhile();
    doAfterThings();
  }

  void halt() override
  {
    long_runner_.stopRunner();
    ExecutionBase::halt();
  }

private:
  LongRunner long_runner_;
};

The library controls creating the executeInSeparateThread() thread and calling halt() in a different thread. What locks, etc should I use to ensure that halt() always correctly interrupts executeInSeparateThread()?
The trickiness that's throwing me is that stopRunner() only interrupts runForAwhile() if it's currently running. Therefore, once stopRunner() is called in halt(), if runForAwhile() has not yet started, the thread synchronization needs to ensure it will never start.
It's not necessary for this question, but if you're curious, LongRunner is really moveit::task_constructor::Task (plan() and preempt()) and ExecutionBase is BT::ThreadedAction

the thread synchronization needs to ensure it will never start. i don't think this is required, the only requirement is that if stopRunner is called before runForAwhile then runForAwhile will quit as soon as possible, which is already true for the type library you linked .... also the libraries you linked already use atomics for those things so you don't need to add any synchronization on top

"What locks, etc should I use to ensure that halt() always correctly interrupts executeInSeparateThread()?" - I wouldn't use the word "interrupt"  since this is (from what I could see) done on a rather high level (C++ synchronization primitives) although I noticed that the word is used in a comment in the lib: /// interrupt current planning (or execution) void preempt();. From what I can see, preempt() doesn't trigger any interrupts in the hardware sense that I can see though. So, just use the regular C++ synchronization primitives.

It looks to me like SyncActionNode::halt() calls (and only calls) TreeNode::resetStatus() and that member does nothing if the status is IDLE. That seems likely to invite the issue you have. If the node is in the preliminaries of running but not yet moved its status off IDLE then the halt() will be ignored. I notice that BT::ThreadedAction::executeTick() sets halt_requested_=false (if it finds status of IDLE... A halt request flag should normally be at least set when the object isn't running in a thread and reset after it's stopped (e.g. when join() returns).

one problem i think you can run into is that if halt is called after runForAwhile has finished, in the library you linked this will stop the next invocation of the function, not the last one, because of how it resets its internals automatically, one way you can go around this is to create a wrapper that keeps track of which invocation was cancelled .... this will be very racy though and you will likely need to add a few locks.

@AhmedAEK, That's what is behind my emphasis on at least, above. If objects are going to be executed, (optionally) halted and then re-executed the potential for 'halt' to 'arrive' late is a risk. In the most complex case some kind of execution object or handle is needed and halt() becomes logically (say) halt(Execution ExecHandle).
The design here appears to be conflating the work-task (may be re-doable) with the execution of that task (once halted cannot be restarted except as a separate execution).

void runForAwhile();
void stopRunner(); // Only interrupts runForAwhile() if it is currently running.

What if stopRunner is called before runForAwhile ?
Any "good" design will still stop runForAwhile if stopRunner was called first, this is what your linked library does, it is as simple as checking an atomic bool.
std::atomic<bool> run = true;
// run = false; !!!!! BAD DESIGN !!
std::thread t{ [&]()
    {
        // run = true; !!!! BAD DESIGN !!
        while (run.load())
        {
            std::cout << "ran!\n";
        }
    } };
// maybe OS preempts this thread here !!
run = false;
t.join();

In the above code we can still get ran! printed, it is a race whether or not you see ran! printed, the standard only guarantees that the loop will eventually break, on the other hand the BAD DESIGN! has many issues like

you cannot actually stop it! because it may not have started yet when you do run = false, you need a wait_for_thread_to_start() method (implemented using a condition variable) to even be able to stop it !
you cannot prevent it from starting! because by the time you call a hypothetical prevent_thread_from_starting(), the thread could have already started ! (the remedy here is to not create the thread in the first place, which is also a race if it is requested by another thread)


Luckily for you the library you linked uses the "good" design, and will check the atomic bool before it starts to do work, it is still a race whether or not any work is done. (storing the bool races with its load on the other thread).
Since you have added your own code around runForAwhile the best you can do is also check whether this bool was set before calling your code and return early ... or maybe not. that's up to you. (If cleanup need to happen, you should let the function run instead of returning early)
  void executeInSeparateThread() override
  {
    if (isHaltRequested())
    {
      // do any clean-up here, ie: resetPreemptRequest
      return;
    }
    doBeforeThings();

    // do you still want to return here if Halt was requested ?
    long_runner_.runForAwhile();

    // is returning here even valid ?! likely not because next code is cleanup
    doAfterThings();
  }

since your linked libraries already use atomic bools you don't need to add any extra synchronization on top, atomics already establish synchronization, and a good library should hide its synchronization primitives from external misuse.

The issue without synchronization is if the sequence of execution is: doBeforeThings() > long_runner_.stopRunner() > long_runner_.runForAwhile() > ExecutionBase::halt(). Since stopRunner() only does anything when runForAwhile() is executing (a later version of the moveit_task_constructor library fixes this, but I've also run into it in other libraries), with that sequence, runForAwhile() won't be interrupted

I'm pretty sure the following code does what I'm trying to do, although it seems pretty convoluted:
class MyExecution : ExecutionBase
{
public:
  void executeInSeparateThread() override
  {
    doBeforeThings();
    std::unique_lock lock(mutex_, std::try_to_lock);
    // stopRunner() has already been called
    if (!lock.owns_lock())
    {
      return;
    }
    long_runner_.runForAwhile();
    lock.unlock();
    doAfterThings();
  }

  void halt() override
  {
    std::unique_lock lock(mutex_, std::defer_lock);
    // Keep calling stopRunner() until we get the lock,
    // indicating runForAwhile() has ended
    while (!lock.try_lock())
    {
      long_runner_.stopRunner();
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
    ExecutionBase::halt();
  }

private:
  LongRunner long_runner_;
  std::mutex mutex_;
};

